# bootstrap: navbar highlight and anchor href is not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a Navbar and highlighting navbar by selecting `active` bootstrap class.

I have tried this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='static/images/logo.png'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>FIFA Automation</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>    
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">     
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-nowrap">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link external" href="/home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link external" href="/about" data-toggle="tab">About us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

JS file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".navbar-nav .nav-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.nav-item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.nav-item').addClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Here, `e.preventDefault();` Added this line for highlighting navbar purpose. But because of that, redirecting to `href` link is not working.

If I remove this line, redirecting to `href` link is working but highlighting navbar is not.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit *class names* according to your own.

```
 $(".navbar .nav-link").on("click", function(){
   $(".navbar").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

or

```
$(".navbar-nav").on("click", function(){
      $(".nav-item a").find(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).